# How do strings allocate memory in c++?

Tags: c++, string, dynamic-memory-allocation

I know that dynamic memory has advantages over setting a fixed size array and and using a portion of it. But in dynamic memory you have to enter the amount data that you want to store in the array. When using strings you can type as many letters as you want(you can even use strings for numbers and then use a function to convert them). This fact makes me think that dynamic memory for character arrays is obsolete compared to strings.

So i wanna know what are the advantages and disadvantages when using strings? When is the space occupied by strings freed? Is maybe the option to free your dynamically allocated memory with delete an advantage over strings? Please explain.

Comment: Strings aren't magic. They're just a library feature.

Comment: @KerrekSB: But it's still better than using your own dynamic memory `char *` code!

Comment: @MatsPetersson: Yes, of course, but the OPs phrasing of "dynamically allocated memory vs strings" is a false dichotomy. Strings *are* (generally) dynamic containers.

Comment: Apparently, the two answers I [linked you to in chat yesterday](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/10?m=11310009#11310009) didn't have the information you are after? Perhaps you could be **a whole lot** more specific about the exact use case you are wondering about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

std::string usually contains an internal dynamically allocated buffer. When you assign data, or if you push back new data, and the current buffer size is not sufficient, a new buffer is allocated with an increased size and the old data is copied or moved to the new buffer. The old buffer is then deallocated.

The main buffer is deallocated when the string goes out of scope. If the string object is a local variable in a function (on the stack), it will deallocate at the end of the current code block. If it's a function parameter, when the function exits. If it's a class member, whenever the class is destroyed.

The advantage of strings is flexibility (increases in size automatically) and safety (harder to go over the bounds of an array). A fixed-size char array on the stack is faster as no dynamic allocation is required. But you should worry about that if you have a performance problem, and not before.

Answer (score 7):

The short answer is "no, there is no drawbacks, only advantages" with `std::string` over character arrays.

Of course, strings do USE dynamic memory, it just hides the fact behind the scenes so you don't have to worry about it.

In answer to you question:  When is the space occupied by strings freed?  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4979705/2372604) post may be helpful.  Basically, `std::string`s are freed once they go out of scope.  Often the compiler can decide when to allocate and release the memory.

Comment: I read an article which tells that string mostly but not  always use dynamic memory allocation here https://www.nextptr.com/tutorial/ta1217154594/cplusplus-stdstring_view-for-better-performance-an-example-use-case#:~:text=The%20std%3A%3Astring_view%2C%20from,the%20object%20does%20not%20matter. Do you know in which case it does not ? Also looks like std::string_view was created with char because using string has a performance disadvantage.

Answer (score 0):

well, your question got me thinking, and then i understood that you are talking about syntax differences, because both ways are dynamic allocating char arrays. the only difference is in the need:

- if you need to create a string containing a sentence then you can, and
  that's fine, not to use `malloc`
- if you want an array and to "play" with it, meaning change or set the cells cording to some method, or changing it's size, then initiating it with `malloc` would be the appropriate way
- the only reason i see to a static allocating `char a[17]` (for example) is for a single purpose string that you need, meaning only when you know the exact size you'll need and it won't change

and one important point the i found:

In dynamic memory allocation, if the memory is being continually allocated but the one allocated for objects that are not in use, is not released, then it can lead to stack overflow condition or memory leak which is a big disadvantage.

Comment: Huh? I have no idea what you are talking about, and more importantly, what the purpose of mentioning stack overflow is in this particular context.

Comment: @MatsPetersson But! But! Stackoverflow is awesome!